# Скрипт для обновлении даты и времени в текстовом документе

Tags: bash, дата

В текстовом документе организовано подобие базы данных: строки со временем и датой.
Формат следующий: `2014-03-25T09:51:34`.

Как возможно сравнить это время с настоящим и если старая дата (вчера и дальше), то поменять на новую (завтра, послезавтра и далее). Спасибо.

Comment: Задача не совсем ясна. Если вам надо из середины строки выдрать дату, проверить и заменить - то думаю надо на перле сделать. А если в bash скрипте с этими датами поработать, то это вполне можно делать командой date. Уточните вопрос, примеры приведите

Comment: @Mike   Да да, именно эта задача: выбрать дату, проверить и заменить. Изначально файл в java классе и время записао как string. Думал легче скриптом, но что там, что там застрял.

Comment: Непонятно по какому принципу заменять эти даты. Вас поэтому и просят привести пример замены. Например, первая строка с прошлой  датой заменяется на завтрашнюю дату, вторая строка с прошлой датой на послезавтрашнюю и т.д. Опишите подробнее алгоритм замены, который вам надо реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт на перле. Использовать в виде `perl time.pl входной-файл >выходной-файл`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;
while(<>)
{
 s/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/chtime($1)/ge;
 print;
}
sub chtime
{
 $time=str2time($_[0]);
 $now=time();
 if($time<($now-24*60*60) ) # проверяем на текущую -24 часа
  {
   $time=$now+24*60*60*3; # текущая +3 дня
   return time2str('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',$time);
  }
 return $_[0];
}
```

Дату выдергивает из произвольного места строки регулярным выражением. Функция `chtime` должна проверить время и вернуть новое время.

Answer (score 0):

если входной файл представляет что-то вроде:

```
$ cat file.in
2014-03-25T09:51:34 line1
2014-03-25T09:51:34 line2
2016-01-07T01:01:01 line3
```

а даты старше сегодняшней надо заменить на текущее время, то можно воспользоваться таким примерно скриптом:

```
$ cat script 
date=/bin/date
infile=./file.in
outfile=./file.out
# %s — это секунды с начала unix-эпохи
polnoch=$($date -d "00:00" +%s)

cat $infile | while read d s; do
  secs=$($date -d $d +%s)
  if [[ $polnoch -gt $secs ]]; then
    d=$($date +%FT%T)
  fi
  echo $d $s
done > $outfile
```

после его запуска:

```
$ bash script
```

в выходном файле получим:

```
$ cat file.out 
2016-01-07T00:33:59 line1
2016-01-07T00:33:59 line2
2016-01-07T01:01:01 line3
```

если же требуется не текущее время, а какое-нибудь другое, то следует соответствующим образом исправить строку:

```
    d=$($date +%FT%T)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=1
while read d; do
DATA=$(egrep -o '201[0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0123][0-9]T[012][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]' <<<"$d")
DATA_T=$(date +%FT%T)
[[ -n $DATA ]] && ((($(date +%s) - $(date -d $DATA +%s))/60/60/24)) && sed -i "${i}s/${DATA}/${DATA_T}/" $1
((i+=1))
done <$1
```

Находит дату в любой позиции каждой строки и при необходимости
меняет на текущую. Запускаем **./script data.txt**